# Согласование числительного

Tags: согласование

Предложение такое: "В гомеопатии страх смерти лечится более сорока препаратами". Что-то у меня сомнение по поводу согласования слова "сорок". Правильно ли все в этом предложении?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно.Сорок, сорока-только две формы. Если не нравится на слух всё предложение, можно изменить:"В гомеопатии для лечения страха смерти есть более сорока препаратов".

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем ответившим!!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "В гомеопатии страх смерти лечится более чем сорока препаратами".

Сравнить: "В Сочи он побеседовал с более чем двадцатью мировыми лидерами".

Comment: Ответ неправильный, или оба варианта возможны ("более сорока препаратами" и "более чем сорока препаратами")?

Answer (score 0):

Числительные 40 и 100 имеют только две формы: сорок (сто) в им.п. и в вин. п и сорока (ста)в остальных.